# Book a specific appointment on a specific day

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I want to book a specific time for the user (start hour and end hour ) and no one else can book at the same time Example Like : John made an appointment on the 5th day of the month at 7 to 8 o'clock i want no one else can booking at the same time and day

and i want to check the Period because if someone like john booking start time 5pm to 8pm
no one can booking like stat 6pm to 7 pm at the same day

How I can Do This in Models Django

I could not find a solution to this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYOYS.png)

im using timing to know how long the booking take
and i dont know what can i should do

enter the link tow show the image of code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the model's `clean` method.

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError 


class OpeningHour(models.Model):
    made_on = models.DateField()
    from_hour = models.TimeField()
    to_hour = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.from_hour} to {self.to_hour}"
  
    def clean(self):
        #Ensure that from_hour is not greater than to_hour
        if self.from_hour > self.to_hour:
            raise ValidationError("Start time can not be greater than end time")  
        in_range = (self.from_hour, self.to_hour)
        filter = OpeningHour.objects.filter(made_on=self.made_on).filter(Q(from_hour__range=in_range) | Q(to_hour__range=in_range)).exists()
        if filter:
            raise ValidationError(f"The booked time ({self.from_hour} to {self.to_hour}) is occupied.")
        return super().clean()
```